How to enable "include credentials" in PHP curl request?
Edited the initial question...
I am making an api call through js and to enable the api server to track origin I have mentioned credentials: "include"
I have successfully executed javascript fetch request from the code below
await fetch("api-path", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8" },
    body: JSON.stringify({ key01: "value01",  key02: "value02" }),
    credentials: "include"
})
.then (async (res) => {
    const jRes = await res.json();
    return jRes;
});

Now, I want to make a similar request using php curl, however, not sure how to send credentials: "include" parameter with the php curl request, so that my origin is read by the api server. Can some one guide for the same?, my php code is shown below
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    $headersArray = array("Content-Type:application/json");
    $rawData = array( "key0" => "value0" );
    $jsonData = json_encode($rawData);
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    ...
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headersArray,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>$jsonData
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $phpObject = json_decode($response, true);
    echo "<br>param 01 value = " . $phpObject["param-01-key"];
    ...
?>


What kind of "credentials" do you want to include with your cURL request? Do you know? See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#including_credentials Also, your question is about a PHP cURL request, and you question contains a Javascript fetch request and some PHP headers. Where's the code for your PHP cURL request? Can you please add this to the question?

Access-Control headers are sent by a server in response to an HTTP request. They're not relevant here. Rather than trying to reverse engineer some JavaScript, consult the API documentation to find out what credentials are required and how they should be sent, and write PHP code for that.

Three paragraphs of waffle. If you wrote the API then you know what credentials you're expecting and how they are to be sent. Tell us that and we can help. Your JavaScript fetch is irrelevant.

I have edited initial question to make it shorter and removed the 4 paras

Thank you. You were right that the credentials are probably sent using headers, and you are using CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER to send headers with the cURL request. The question remains: Which headers does the API need? We can't tell from your question. You could investigate this by reading the API documentation, or by using the browser developer tools. Go to the "network" tab and see which headers are sent with the JS fetch() you do.
